# Databinding and included layouts: Cannot find setter attribute for onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to set an `OnClickListener` for an `<include>`d layout, but receive a data binding error at compile time stating that data binding "Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type android.view.View.OnClickListener".

Context here is that I'm using data binding to inflate the included layout, so that I can pass values into it from a `viewModel` that I've bound to the including layout.

I've tried various syntax for the data binding expression:

- `@{viewModel::onClickFunction}`
- `@{viewModel.onClickFunction}`
- `@{() -> viewModel.onClickFunction()}`
- `@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickFunction()}`
- `@{_ -> viewModel.onClickFunction()}`

I've tried all of the above with `onClickFunction` as a function, and also as an `OnClickListener` object.

Other related questions on Stack Overflow seem to solve this issue by cleaning the project to regenerate the databinding files, but that hasn't worked for me.

Relevant code snippets below:

#### viewModel

```
class MyViewModel() {
    val onClickFunctionAsAListener: OnClickListener = object:OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            //Do something
        }
    }

    fun onClickFunction() {
            //Do something
    }
}
```

#### Including layout

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="full.package.name.MyViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout>
        <include 
            layout="@layout/included_layout"
            android:onClick="@{viewModel.onClickListener}"
            app:customAttribute="@{`someText`}/>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

#### Included layout

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable name="customAttribute" type="String"/>
    </data>

    <TextView
        layout="@layout/included_layout"
        android:text="@{customAttribute}"/>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that you can't actually assign an OnClick handler to an `<include>` tag directly. I managed to get it to work by adding another variable to `IncludedLayout`s data binding class, and then assigning the OnClickListener to `IncudedLayout`s root view in XML.

After the changes, my files looked like this:

#### viewModel

```
class MyViewModel() {
    val onClickFunction: OnClickListener = object:OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

#### Including layout

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="full.package.name.MyViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout>
        <include 
            layout="@layout/included_layout"
            app:onClick="@{viewModel.onClickListener}"
            app:customAttribute="@{`someText`}/>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

#### Included layout

```
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable name="customAttribute" type="String"/>
        <variable name="onClick" type="android.view.View.OnClickListener"/>
    </data>

    <TextView
        layout="@layout/included_layout"
        android:text="@{customAttribute}"
        android:onClick="@{onClick}"/>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`include` tag does not support `onClick` method directly. While the selected answer is correct, instead of passing `onClickLister` to `include` layout (or having custom `@BindingAdapter`, which is also another solution), I would just wrap my `include` inside a `ViewGroup` and `onClick` on `ViewGroup`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="@{()-> viewModel.yourFunction()}">
    <include layout="@layout/custom_layout"/>
```

It's a workaround, but works as charm.